# Javascrip HTTP Post and Oauth 2.0

Tags: apex, json, authentication

I am trying to query a field in visual force page using Javascrip and HTTP Requests (Rest API OAUTH 2.0). But I am not sure how I can get the access Token or the Bearer automatically after every time a user logs in. every how long does the Access token get expired? how can I use their password and username to make the first handshake and grab the access token. I am kind of all over place on this. This needs to be in Ajax, and get the results back in JSON
I am trying doing this inside salesforce using visual force page. Its not an outside App

I have read this but I dont wanna use any class for this 
https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/07/using-apex-to-integrate-salesforce.html

I just wanna know how I can get the access token for different user one they login and go to the apex page without the user give a permission

I dont wanna do APP https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you [edit] your question to include any code you might have written?

Comment: @battery.cord I am not even sure if it is possible right now. I used postman and I was able to query all the stuff that I wanted to see with my own Oauth but that is only with my own password and username. But how do I get the access token via javascript for all every users that login , I have read this https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/07/using-apex-to-integrate-salesforce.html

Comment: It sounds like you're going about this the (very) hard way. I'd suggest taking a look at the [Salesforce AJAX Toolklit](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.ajax.meta/ajax/sforce_api_ajax_introducing.htm)

Comment: @DerekF Perfect I was looking for exactly that

Comment: @DerekF Is there anything wrong with this  'type: "GET",
                url: "/services/data/v35.0/query?q="+''+ {!URLENCODE('SELECT Name, Name FROM Contact WHERE Accountid =' + "'001R0000011zC8C'" )}",'

Comment: I'll type up an answer.

Comment: @bez Now that I think about it, I'd like to hear what it is that you're trying to do with your visualforce page. The reason I ask is because while the AJAX Toolkit may work, it might not be the best tool for the job. Are you trying to grab a list of all `Contacts` related to a given `Account`? How are you getting that Account Id (is it hard-coded, or do you get that data from somewhere)?

Comment: @DerekF yes basically what I wanna do is that without customer submission I wanna be able to provide some results to them this way I dont have to right any controller or any test case for it, and the page doesnt need to get reloaded. Now all i have to learn is how to loop through the results in javascript and display them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you seem to be working from within Salesforce, you can simply use the [Salesforce AJAX Toolkit](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.ajax.meta/ajax/sforce_api_ajax_introducing.htm).

The main advantage there is that you don't need to handle authentication at all.

In one of the example pages towards the end of that documentation, there is an example of how to issue a query.

```
result = sforce.connection.query("Select Name, Id from User");

records = result.getArray("records");
for (var i=0; i< records.length; i++) {
    var record = records[i];
    log(record.Name + " -- " + record.Id);
}
```

That said, I'd normally advise creating/using a controller extension to handle this type of thing (especially if you would otherwise only need to issue a query once for the lifetime of a page). It all depends on what exactly you're trying to accomplish.